# Hooking read syscall

Tags: hook, system-calls

I have a kernel module that is hooking the read syscall. One of the things I have to do, is capture the contents of the read syscall that is doing an external program submitted by my teacher.

With the strace, I was able to see how the program of my teacher is doing the read:

```
read(6, "\v\0\0\0\tExercise1", 14)
```

And the read hooking is working, the problem is, I don't know how to read the contents from inside the new read function because if I am correctly *buf is empty and is not filled until the original syscall read is called. So, in theory I should read directly from the file descriptor, but without using read syscall I don't know how to do that.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code of your hooking module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your hooking function should be something like the following :

```c
size_t my_hooked_read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbytes)
{
  size_t ret;

  //Do something before original call

  ret = original_read(fildes, buf, nbytes); //call the original read !

  //Do something after original call
  //buf is correctly filled here !

  return ret;
}
```

If you want to read the content of `buf`, read it after the original call.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but the hooking function is not the problem, is more or less exactly your function. My problem is located on: //Do something before original call.

What I want to do is read the buf... but in theory is empty because the read syscall is not finished, so I should read the contents of the file descriptor. Problem is I don't know how to do that.

Comment: is there any reason why you don't read the buffer **after** the original call ?

Comment: is that possible from a kernel module? In theory I should read with the hooking because is what we are studying...

Comment: oks, you were right,it have to do after the original call is done. Thanks!